# emberjs desired page wont open on "right click open in new tab"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, serialization, ember.js, handlebars.js

So here is the javascript class emberjs code with

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({:
....
....
....
....
showUser() {
  this.replaceRoute('user', this.get('user'));
  this.close();
}
```

and this is the handlebars with html file code:

```
<a href {{action "showUser"}}>{{username}} {{user-status user currentUser=currentUser}}</a>
```

The app is on Ruby on Rails.

There is a topics page and a user profile page. What this does is opens up a pop up user badge and allow users to click on the usernames and it redirects them to that users profile page. Clicking this works fine and redirects the user to the user page from this topics page that they are on. But I would like users to RIGHT CLICK, OPEN IN NEW TAB. That just opens the same topics page.

After researching on ember I came to find out the transitionToRoute in the first piece of code shows that the model probably is serialized into the URL, ultimately using the serialized hook of the rout. Why do I think that this is the cause? I don't know! I also tried replaceRoute method but that does the same. Help? :)

Comment: Because you are calling an action and not actually linking to anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the helper `{{#link-to 'user' userModel}}`, where 'user' and `userModel` is the model for the route, this will create a link that can be opened in a new tab.

Ember actions can not be routed by the browser, as they are not links, they are internal routes used by ember in JavaScript, same goes for `transitionToRoute` in controllers and `transitionTo` in routes.

more info [here](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/links/#toc_the-code-link-to-code-helper)